# Check mouse in one Model or not?

Tags: c#-4.0, xna-4.0

In XNA 4.0 3D. I want to Drag and Drop one model 3D.So,I must check mouse in a Model or not. My problem is I don't know change position and rate this Model from 3D to 2D. It's related Matrix View and Matrix Projection of camera??
This is my code:
http://www.mediafire.com/?3835txmw3amj7pe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article on msdn: [Selecting an Object with a Mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203905.aspx).

From that article:

```
MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
int mouseX = mouseState.X;
int mouseY = mouseState.Y;

Vector3 nearsource = new Vector3((float)mouseX, (float)mouseY, 0f);
Vector3 farsource = new Vector3((float)mouseX, (float)mouseY, 1f);

Matrix world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);

Vector3 nearPoint = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(nearsource,
    proj, view, world);

Vector3 farPoint = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(farsource,
    proj, view, world);

// Create a ray from the near clip plane to the far clip plane.
Vector3 direction = farPoint - nearPoint;
direction.Normalize();
Ray pickRay = new Ray(nearPoint, direction);
```

For `proj` and `view` use your own projection and view matrices accordingly.

Now when you have your `Ray`, you need to have a `BoundingBox` or a `BoundingSphere` (or multiple) that are roughly encompassing your model.

A **simple solution** is to use `BoundingSphere` properties of `ModelMesh` for each mesh in your `Model.Meshes`.

```
foreach(ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
    if(Ray.Intersects(mesh.BoundingSphere))
    {
        //the mouse is over the model!
        break;
    }
}
```

Since `BoundingSphere` of each `ModelMesh` is going to encompass all vertices in that mesh, it **might not be the most precise representation of the mesh** if it is not  roughly *round* (i.e. if it is very long). This means that the above code could be saying that the mouse intersects the object, when visually it is way off.

The alternative is to **create your bounding volumes manually**. You make instances of `BoundingBox` or `BoundingSphere` objects as suits your need, and manually change their dimensions and positions based on runtime requirements. This requires slightly more work, but it **isn't hard**.

Comment: Hi Niko Draskovic, Can you guide me save and load a game in XNA 4.0?? Thanks!!